# constructor and destructor between two different class

Tags: c++

So, I try to create two class that pointing to each other (has a pointer to the other class as private variable) here is the code:

```
class Fruit
{
public:
    Fruit(){
    }
private:
    Plant *thisPlant;
}

class Plant
{
public:
    Plant(){
      thisFruit= new Fruit();
    }
private:
    Fruit *thisFruit;
}
```

I am not sure what should I put in the Fruit constructor. I think I can't put new Plant() because it will pointing to a new plant, and it also will create an error. I want to have something like this: Plant has a variable pointing to Fruit. And the Fruit has a variable pointing to the Plant. Because I will use some Fruit's public method in Plant class, vice versa.

Regarding the destructor, I just want to clarify one thing. when I destroy the Fruit variable, if I do not put command "delete thisPlant;" the object Plant isn't destroyed right? thx

Comment: At the risk of sounding snarky: do you know what inheritance is?

Comment: yeah I understand a little bit about inheritance. However, I don't think I can use is-a relation. I want to use has-a relation between these two class

Comment: @suszterpatt if thats snarky than its catching, because it was the first thing that came to my mind too.

Comment: @Smith, you are correct about the has-a relationship. But you gotta ask yourself if it really works both ways.

Comment: @smithNeil: Do you really need it on the object level though? Can two objects of the same `Fruit` type have different `Plant`s associated to them?

Comment: You are aware that you're creating a recursive object? A `Fruit` points to a newly created `Plant`, which points to a newly created `Fruit`, which points to a newly created `Plant`,...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to put `new Fruit` in the `Plant` constructor and `new Plant` in the `Fruit` constructor, you'd end up with infinite recursion. Creating a `Plant` would create a `Fruit` would create a `Plant` would create a `Fruit`, and so on.

```
Plant ---> Fruit ---> Plant ---> Fruit ---> ...
```

But this clearly **isn't the relationship you want**. A `Plant` has a `Fruit`, but that `Fruit` doesn't have a different `Plant`. It surely wants to have a pointer to the `Plant` that it is a part of.

```
Plant <--> Fruit
```

To do this, your `Fruit` constructor should take a single parameter of type `Plant*`, to allow the `Plant` to pass a pointer to itself to the `Fruit` that it has.

```
class Plant;

class Fruit
{
 public:
  Fruit(Plant* parent){
    parent = parent;
  }
 private:
  Plant* parent;
};

class Plant
{
 public:
  Plant(){
    fruit= new Fruit(this);
  }
 private:
  Fruit* fruit;
};
```

Notice that the `Plant` constructor passes `this` to its `Fruit`. Now there is a two way relationship between the `Plant` and `Fruit`. The `Plant` knows about its `Fruit` and the `Fruit` knows about its `Plant`.

Now, remember that every `new` must have a `delete`. That means that in the destructor for `Plant`, you should do `delete fruit;`. When you destroy a `Plant`, its destructor will destroying its `Fruit`. You *must not* then make the `Fruit` do `delete parent;` because its parent is already being destroyed. The `Plant` is responsible for destroying its `Fruit`, not the other way around.

Comment: Note that this won't compile, since `Plant` is unknown in `Fruit(Plant *)`.

Comment: I think Zeta is saying you should add a forward declaration before `Fruit`

Answer (score 0):

By means of the *'natural' semantic hierarchy rules* class `Fruit` should take a `Plant*` pointer as constructor argument, and never should touch it with it's destructor.

Further it looks like concrete classes inheriting from `Plant` class should be responsible to create an instance of the `Fruit` class (using s.th. like `new ConcreteFruit(this)`). You can provide a Destructor implementation in the `Plant`base class that will destroy this instance on destruction.

I think `Fruit` and `Plant` could be either abstract classes, where you'll derive concrete pairs like

```
class CherryTree : public Plant 
{ 
    // ... 
}

class Cherry : public Fruit 
{ 
    Cherry(CheryTree* plant) : Fruit(plant) {}
    // ... 
}
```

or you'll need some mechanism build the pairs using class attributes (e.g. `std::string plantName` <=> `std::string fruitName`).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of the hen-egg problem you can use templates:

```
template <class PlantType>
class Fruit_impl
{
public:
    Fruit_impl(PlantType * parent = 0){
        if(parent == 0)
            parent = new PlantType(this);
        thisPlant = parent;
    }
private:
    PlantType *thisPlant;
};

class Plant
{
public:
    typedef Fruit_impl<Plant> fruit_type;
    Plant(fruit_type * parent = 0){
        if(parent == 0)
            parent = new Fruit<Plant>(this);
        thisFruit = parent;
    }
private:
    fruit_type * thisFruit;
};

typedef Fruit_impl<Plant> Fruit;
```

Note that you need to give some kind of control mechanism in order to avoid recursion (see [sftrabbit's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14943846/1139697) answer).

However, note that in the implementation given above there's a circular dependency, thus it is quite difficult to get delete the objects.